# How to get replies of a comment?

Tags: comments

Is there a way to get replies of a comment by its ID? I have searched on google but could not find anything about it.

For example, I have a comment with ID 123

I want to display all the replies that comment ID 123 has.

I have tried something like the following but it did not work:

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'approve',
    'ID' => 123,
    'number' => '5',
    'post_id' => 73871,
    'comment_parent' => 0

);
$comments = get_comments($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

As `comment_ID` is a unique value, there is no need to include the `post_id` in the arguments.

This works fine for me:

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'approve', 
    'number' => '5',
    'parent' => 3194
);
$comments = get_comments($args);
```

This will return 5 approved comments whose parent is the comment with the `comment_ID` 3194.

Sample output could be done with something like this:

```
foreach($comments as $child_comment) {
    echo $child_comment->comment_ID;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found it, please corrent me if I am wrong:

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'approve', 
    'number' => '5',
    'post_id' => 73871,
    'parent' => 123

);
$comments = get_comments($args);
```

**EDIT:** not quite, it seems it returns the first reply only. The rest are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct so far but incomplete.

You need a foreach loop after your code. So it will be like:

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'approve', 
    'number' => '5',
    'post_id' => 73871,
    'parent' => 123
);

$comments = get_comments($args);

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment->comment_content; // echo all the other fields you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `foreach` loop, you need to search for each comment if it has any replies submitted.

`$replies = get_comments( array( 'parent' => $comment->comment_ID, 'status' => 'approve', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );`

please have a look at this plugin https://github.com/mukto90/comment-search/blob/master/cb-comment-search.php

it'll help you search by a comment id and show all of its replies (and maybe their replies too).